# Encountered "/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 8: /etc/default/grub: 4: not found" error while updating

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

Whenever I use

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8,311 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 256191 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (4.15.0-46.49) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 8: /etc/default/grub: 4: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `cat /etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT= 4
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors are due to a space in line 8 in **/etc/default/grub** file. GRUB would think that it's some kind of argument instead of value. You need to remove that.

- Open **/etc/default/grub** with `sudo` privileges using nano (or pico, whichever you prefer)

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Delete the space in line 8 before `4`
- Save file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Update GRUB

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Retry `autoremove` command